# window.pageYOffset not working in if loop

Tags: javascript

I am using the following kind of code and i dont know why this is not working

```
window.onload = function (){
   if(window.pageYOffset >= 10){
      alert("pageYOffset: " + window.pageYOffset)
   }
}
```

By not working i mean that the alert box is not prompted

Is there a way to activate the function on scrolling instead of me doing it onload using **Pure Javascript**

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: "Not working" isn't a useful description of the problem.  You need to include both the **expected** results and the **actual** results.  In addition, any messages from the error console are helpful.

Comment: When a page loads it usually doesn't scroll you past the beginning, so this appears to work correctly.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher By not working i mean that the alert box is not prompted

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `onscroll` event not the `onload` event:

```
window.onscroll = function (){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 10){
        alert("pageYOffset: " + window.pageYOffset)
    }
}
```

Fiddle: [`http://jsfiddle.net/9WQPj/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/9WQPj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a hash tag in your URL, with the appropriate anchor in the document, window.pageYOffset will always be 0 on page load and won't change until you scroll.

Comment: @user2623786 - Of course the alert box isn't displayed!  The condition `window.pageYOffset >= 10` is false, so the inside of the `if` statement isn't executed.